# GPS on Windows Tablets?

Tags: c#, gps, tablet

I have looked at many open source GPS programs that can parse GPS data from an external GPS device that connects to the computer via a serial port.

But what about built-in GPS devices like a Panasonic Toughbook (a Windows XP Tablet)? Do these devices transmit their GPS data through a serial port?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure they do broadcast their GPS data through the serial port (or can be easily configured to do so). I've written C# code for Garmin GPS-enabled PDAs, and their GPS data can be accessed either through P/Invoke calls to a proprietary DLL on the device, or just by reading the NMEA sentences broadcast on the serial port.  So I imagine built-in GPS in PC-type computers works the same way.  I can't find any confirmation of this online, however.

Comment: As an unrelated piece of advice: never throw your Toughbook down on the deck of a ship in order to demonstrate how tough it is. I've seen this, so I know that a Toughbook isn't *that* tough. :)